# Return tables parent name from entry name in mySql

Tags: mysql

I have a database with multiple tables in MySql and im trying to figure out how to basiclly make a search of an entry and return all the tables that contain that entry. I dont need the whole table but just the TABLE_NAME.

Currently i have this in index.php:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_COMMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='maps'") or die(mysql_error());
```

And then i want to make another page that displays a table of what i described.
Hope you understood what i mean.

EDIT.
Okey, so i come up with this code.
I kind of does what i want, but now i want to search through each row in the table, not the Table Name.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='maps' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE "%Search term%"
```

EDIT2.

Now in my .php file i have the following. 'a' for test.

```
$qu = "set @@group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
set @schema := 'maps';
set @search := '%a%';

set @sql = (
    select group_concat(concat(
        'select distinct \'', c.TABLE_NAME, '\' as table_name, ',
        '\'', c.COLUMN_NAME, '\' as column_name ',
        'from `', @schema, '`.`', c.TABLE_NAME, 
        '` where `', c.COLUMN_NAME, '` like \'', @search , '\''
    ) separator ' union all ')
    from information_schema.`COLUMNS` c
    where c.TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
);
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;"
$query = mysql_query($qu) or die(mysql_error());
```

and

```
                <?php
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                    {
                        $f1 = $row['TABLE_NAME'];
                        $f2 = $row['TABLE_NAME'];
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#"><?php echo $f1 ?></a></td>
                    <td><?php echo $f2 ?></td>
                </tr>
```

If you could help that would mean alot, you've already solved it but i'm so new to this so im not sure how to implement it heh, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically construct a prepared statement.

```
set @@group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
set @schema := 'maps';
set @search := '%Search term%';

set @sql = (
    select group_concat(concat(
        'select distinct \'', c.TABLE_NAME, '\' as table_name, ',
        '\'', c.COLUMN_NAME, '\' as column_name ',
        'from `', @schema, '`.`', c.TABLE_NAME, 
        '` where `', c.COLUMN_NAME, '` like \'', @search , '\''
    ) separator ' union all ')
    from information_schema.`COLUMNS` c
    where c.TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
);

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
```

The constructed statement will search for '%Search term%' in every column of every table and return the `table_name` and `column_name` for every column that contains the search term.

You can also construct the same query with PHP:

```php
$schema = 'maps';
$search = '%Search term%';

$query1 = "
    select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
    from information_schema.`COLUMNS`
    where c.TABLE_SCHEMA = {$schema}
";

$result1 mysql_query($query1);
$queryParts = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    $table  = $row['TABLE_NAME'];
    $column = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];
    $queryPart = "
        select distinct '{$table}' as table_name, '{$column}' as column_name
        from `{$schema}`.`{$table}`
        where `{$column}` like '{$search}'
    ";
    $queryParts[] = $queryPart;
}
$unionQuery = implode(' union all ', $queryParts);

$result2 = mysql_query($unionQuery);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    echo $row['table_name'] . '.' . $row['column_name'] . '<br>';
}
```

Note: The created query can be very very slow.

Note 2: As long as it's not too late you should switch from mysql-extention to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or better to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Thanks! I get this though. Any suggestions?

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized statement type. (near "prepare" at position 0)
SQL-fråga:

prepare stmt from @sql

MySQL sa: Dokumentation

#1146 - Table 'maps.ak' doesn't exist

Comment: @FelixEklöf - suggestions? Do you have any troubles with my solution?

Comment: I ran it in Phpmyadmin in Mysql it gave me an error, probably im doing something wrong hah, sorry. It says: Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized statement type. (near "prepare" at position 0)
SQL-fråga:

prepare stmt from @sql

MySQL sa: Dokumentation

#1146 - Table 'maps.ak' doesn't exist

Comment: @FelixEklöf - Select the correct DB (maps) or use the updated query.

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you so much. It says it returns a number of lines in Phpmyadmin but i doesn't show them but i think it will in the php code. I'm very greatful :)

Comment: I'm sorry to ask so much, I just started with MySql and PHP. But in my .php file i have the following now.

Comment: I added an edit2, I didn't really specify that I was gonna use in it php i noticed but do you have an idea on this?